# Generate a sequence of numbers with repeated intervals

Tags: r, numbers, sequence

I am trying to create sequences of number of 6 cases, but with 144 cases intervals.

Like this one for example

```
c(1:6, 144:149, 288:293)

1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293
```

How could I generate automatically such a sequence with

```
seq
```

or with another function ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I find the `sequence` function to be helpful in this case. If you had your data in a structure like this:

```
(info <- data.frame(start=c(1, 144, 288), len=c(6, 6, 6)))
#   start len
# 1     1   6
# 2   144   6
# 3   288   6
```

then you could do this in one line with:

```
sequence(info$len) + rep(info$start-1, info$len)
#  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293
```

Note that this solution works even if the sequences you're combining are different lengths.

Comment: Yeah, given the abnormal intervals in the OP's example, storing the structure explicitly like that is probably a good idea.

Comment: From the `?` page,  "Note that sequence <- function(nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len)) and it mainly exists in reverence to the very early history of R."   Sort of like Frank's answer.

Comment: @josilber - I still have to fill *manually* the `c(1, 144, 288)` ? what if I want 10 sequences or 100 sequences of 6 digits ? What would be your solution ? thanks

Comment: @giacomoV if there is no pattern to the starting points and lengths, then yes of course you will need to specify them manually. If there is a pattern to the starting points and lengths then it will be easier. For instance if you wanted 100 sequences of length 6 with the starting points increasing by 144 each time starting at 0 you would use `info <- data.frame(start=seq(0, by=144, length.out=100), len=6)`.

Comment: Since R >= 4.0.0, `sequence` has now a built-in parameter `from` which helps a lot! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70581941/13460602).

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach:

```
unlist(lapply(c(0L,(1:2)*144L-1L),`+`,seq_len(6)))
# or...
unlist(lapply(c(1L,(1:2)*144L),function(x)seq(x,x+5)))
```

Here's a way I like a little better:

```
rep(c(0L,(1:2)*144L-1L),each=6) + seq_len(6)
```

Generalizing...

```
rlen  <- 6L
rgap  <- 144L
rnum  <- 3L

starters <- c(0L,seq_len(rnum-1L)*rgap-1L)

rep(starters, each=rlen) + seq_len(rlen)
# or...
unlist(lapply(starters+1L,function(x)seq(x,x+rlen-1L)))
```

Comment: I feel like there should be a more elegant solution to this problem, though.

Comment: unlist(lapply(...)) can be replaced with sapply

Comment: @hedgedandlevered Yeah, I tried that too, but it gives a matrix... and if I do sapply with simplify=FALSE, I get back to the lapply result. Could do `c(sapply(...))`, I suppose

Comment: In OP's desired output the first interval is not equal to the others (143 vs. 144). May be an oversight on their part.

Comment: @plafort Yeah, I think it should start at 1, 145, 289, probably. Anyway, the adaptation to that case is pretty clear (and what I accidentally wrote in my first version of the answer): `starters <- (1:rnum-1L)*rgap`

Comment: This was my solution, but I don't know how to adjust it for the mixed intervals `(1:293)[c(rep(T,6L), rep(F, 137L))]`

Comment: Yeah, because they are not uniform, there is no natural extension, I guess.

Comment: Instead of `seq_len(6)` you can just use (1:6)

Comment: @MikeWise Yeah, `seq_len` is just a little faster, they say, though I doubt that matters in this application. Just habit. Also, for the "generalization", I'd have to write `\`:\`(1,rlen)` which is kind of awkward.

Comment: thanks again for your help everybody ! Can I accept the answer or you think new developments are about to come ?

Comment: @giacomoV There's no rush to accept. I'm not crazy about my answer, so I'd just as well see you leave the question open for a day or two and see if something better is found.

Comment: @Vlo, that's actually documented behavior under `?c`-- `c` strips a lot of attributes, and a `matrix` is pretty much a `vector` with dimensional attributes.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done using `seq` or `seq.int`

```
x = c(1, 144, 288)
c(sapply(x, function(y) seq.int(y, length.out = 6)))

#[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293
```

As @Frank mentioned in the comments here is another way to achieve this using @josilber's data structure *(This is useful particularly when there is a need of different sequence length for different intervals)*

```
c(with(info, mapply(seq.int, start, length.out=len)))

#[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293
```

Comment: Yeah, this is good. I find it weird that I can't get the result in integers even if I switch to `x = c(1L, 144L, 288L)`, though. I think this is a flaw in how `seq` treats `length.out`... `seq.int` seems to do the "right" thing, fortunately.

Comment: Yes, I know. The result of `seq(1L,length.out=6)` should be an integer vector is my point. I'm criticizing how the function works, not your answer (which seems the best so far to me). Your answer would work "better" (to my mind), though, if `x` were an integer and `seq.int` were used in place of `seq` so that the end result is an integer vector (like the OP's example).

Comment: You could expand the capability by defining a `sublength <- c(6,6,6)` and setting `length.out=sublength` , so that each sequence could be of a different length.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Unfortunately, `seq`/`seq.int` is not vectorised in the `length.out` argument. That just means `mapply` would be the way to go, though, instead of `sapply`. Using josilber's data structure, `c(with(info, mapply(seq.int, start, length.out=len)))`

Comment: I think @Frank has really hit the nail on the head here --  `seq` is not vectorized in any way at all, making it really annoying to use for these sorts of problems!

Comment: @josilber Oh, I'd figured `seq` was vectorized in some other arg, but I see that you're right. Anyway, I would still prefer the `mapply` here, to construct the sequences directly rather than arithmetically. I can read that line of code and guess what it's doing.

Comment: @Frank seems like a matter of preference then :)

Answer (score 3):

From [R >= 4.0.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000653.html), you can now do this in one line with `sequence`:

```r
sequence(c(6,6,6), from = c(1,144,288))
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293
```

The first argument, `nvec`, is the length of each sequence; the second, `from`, is the starting point for each sequence.

As a function, with `n` being the number of intervals you want:

```r
f <- function(n) sequence(rep(6,n), from = c(1,144*1:(n-1)))
f(3)
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293
```

Comment: Nice -- this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using R 3.3.2.  OSX 10.9.4

I tried:

```
a<-c()  # stores expected sequence
f<-288  # starting number of final sub-sequence
it<-144 # interval
for (d in seq(0,f,by=it))
{
    if (d==0)
    {
        d=1
    }
    a<-c(a, seq(d,d+5))
    print(d)
}
print(a)
```

AND the expected sequence stores in a.

`[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293`

And another try:

```
a<-c()  # stores expected sequence
it<-144 # interval
lo<-4   # number of sub-sequences
for (d in seq(0,by=it, length.out = lo))
{
    if (d==0)
    {
        d=1
    }
    a<-c(a, seq(d,d+5))
    print(d)
}
print(a)
```

The result:

`[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293 432 433 434 435 436 437`

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this with `cumsum` function

```
seq_n <- 3 # number of sequences
rep(1:6, seq_n) + rep(c(0, cumsum(rep(144, seq_n-1))-1), each = 6)
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6 144 145 146 147 148 149 288 289 290 291 292 293
```

No need to calculate starting values of sequences as in the @josilber's solution, but the length of a sequence has to be constant.